# Heat map with personalised colours

Tags: python, r, tableau-api, heatmap

I'm looking for an easy way to create a custom heat map (in Python, or R, or Tableau). I can't figure out how to personalise colours as I need them.

Basically, I have a .tsv file with feature and their ranking. The ranking goes, for example, from 1 to 10 and from -1 to -10 in the same file.

I need to have white for zeros. Then, darker colours for 1 and -1 that then becomes lighter. So, for example, I need to have dark red for 1 and light red for 10, and then dark blue for -1 and light blue for -10.

Any idea on how I could obtain this result?

---

edit:
This is how my data look:

```
structure(list(Features = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L), .Label = c("char_per_tok", "cpos_dist_AUX", "cpos_dist_NUM", 
"dep_dist_aux", "dep_dist_nummod", "dep_freq_aux", "dep_freq_nmod", 
"dep_freq_nummod", "in_dict", "in_dict_types", "in_FO", "in_FO_types", 
"itwac_forme", "itwac_lemmi", "n_prepositional_chains", "prep_dist_3", 
"prep_freq_1", "prep_freq_3", "subj_post", "verb_edges_dist_7", 
"verb_edges_freq_7"), class = "factor"), A10 = c(1L, -14L, -6L, 
-8L, -5L, -7L, 3L, -3L, -1L, -11L, -2L, -4L, 0L, 59L, 4L, -9L, 
2L, -10L, 0L, -13L, -12L), A11 = c(3L, -14L, -6L, -8L, -5L, -7L, 
4L, -4L, -1L, -11L, -2L, -3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, -9L, 5L, -10L, 0L, 
-13L, -12L), A12 = c(3L, 0L, -3L, -5L, -2L, -4L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, -6L, 0L, -7L, 0L, -9L, -8L), A13 = c(3L, 
0L, -3L, 0L, -2L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, -4L, 
0L, -5L, 0L, 0L, 0L), A14 = c(1L, 0L, -3L, 0L, -2L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, -4L, 0L, -5L, 0L, 0L, 0L), A15 = c(2L, 
0L, -3L, 0L, -2L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), A16 = c(0L, 0L, -4L, -5L, -1L, 0L, 0L, -2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -3L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Features", 
"A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A16"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Comment: What have you done so far? An example of how you have created a heatmap without your specified colours would be helpful to understand where you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R you can use `ggplot2` library, `geom_tile` to specify what is plotted and `scale_fill_gradientn` to specify the colors. Here is an example:

```
#diamonds + column rank with a range of -10:10
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
diamonds_1= data.frame(diamonds, rank = sample(c(-10:10), nrow(diamonds), replace = T))


ggplot(data = diamonds_1)+
  geom_tile(aes(color, cut, fill = rank))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("lightblue", "blue", "white", "red", "pink"),
                       values = scales::rescale(c(-10, -1, 0, 1, 10)))+
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

EDIT: with provided data (I imported it to object `z`)

```
z_melt = reshape2::melt(z, id.vars = 1 ) #convert to long format
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = z_melt)+
  geom_tile(aes(y = Features,  x = variable, fill = value))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#ccccff", "lightblue", "blue", "white", "red", "#ff7f7f", "#ffcccc"),
                       values = scales::rescale(c(min(z_melt$value), -10, -1, 0, 1, 10, max(z_melt$value))),
                       breaks = c(-10, 0, 10, 40),
                       labels=c(-10, 0, 10, 40))+                           
  coord_equal()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is actually the type of coloring I was looking for!

Comment: I added a picture of my data. Can you please explain me how to plot them so that I obtain the same result of your picture?

Comment: @Bet please provide data with `dput` or at least in the form of text table.

Comment: Thank you! is there a way to still have 'white' for zero values? Just like what you did in the first table

Comment: @Bet I am sorry I assumed the fill variable is in: -10 - 10 range. Fixed the graph.

Answer (score 0):

in R, you can use the `scales` package to generate the color values.

To generate the colors, use `gradient_n_pal`.  Choose the color you want for the negative values, the color for the positives, and then place `"white"` between them.  `seq(0, 1, length.out = 21)` creates a vector of length 21 that sets the fading.

```
gradient <- scales::gradient_n_pal(c("purple", "white", "green"))(seq(0, 1, length.out = 21))
```

This trivial barplot shows the result

```
library(ggplot2)

Dframe <- data.frame(x = factor(-10:10)) 

ggplot(data = Dframe,
       mapping = aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_bar(fill = gradient)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create the colour chart in **Tableau**: If you want individual colours for each rank simply drag your [Ranking] dimension to colour. If you want a banded output you can create a colour key calculated field, firstly assign a value to each ranking by creating a new calculated field like:

```
If [Ranking] = -10 then "Cold"
ElseIf [Ranking] = -9 then "Cold"
ElseIf [Ranking] = -8 then "Cold"
ElseIf [Ranking] = -7 then "Cold"
ElseIf [Ranking] = -6 then "Cold"
ElseIf [Ranking] = -5 then "Warm"
ElseIf [Ranking] = -4 then "Warm"
ElseIf [Ranking] = -3 then "Warm"
ElseIf [Ranking] = -2 then "Warm"
ElseIf [Ranking] = -1 then "Warm"
ElseIf [Ranking] = -0 then "Warm"
ElseIf [Ranking] = 1 then "Warm"
ElseIf [Ranking] = 2 then "Warm"
ElseIf [Ranking] = 3 then "Warm"
ElseIf [Ranking] = 4 then "Warm"
ElseIf [Ranking] = 5 then "Hot"
ElseIf [Ranking] = 6 then "Hot"
ElseIf [Ranking] = 7 then "Hot"
ElseIf [Ranking] = 8 then "Hot"
ElseIf [Ranking] = 9 then "Hot"
ElseIf [Ranking] = 10 then "Hot"
else "Unknown ranking"  end
```

Drag this field to colour and you can apply a palate of your choice to it.

This is a slightly long winded way of writing the calculated field, depending on the formatting of your ranking field you could use `between` number bands instead, but writing it this way makes it clear what's going on for each score.

Comment: A case statement is less verbose